# Positioning a number into ordered summands

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, permutations

I have a question that

"In how many ways can we position $6$ into ordered summands. As for example we can write $3$ as $(1,1,1),(1,2), (2,1)$ i.e $3$ ways. Is there any formula or any trick besides ordering it separately?

Comment: As the first number in the ordered sum, you can choose any number from 1 to 6.  As for the rest of the ordered sum, it is a smaller version of this problem. Can you try writing a recurrence for it?

Comment: What you’re talking about are [*compositions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) of $6$, except that you’re excluding the one-term composition $(6)$.

Answer (score 2):

One way to think of this is as follows:

In forming any such summand-list of the number $6$, consider $6$ as consisting of six $1$s. We build the summand-list one $1$ at a time.

We begin with an empty summand-list and add the first $1$. There is only one way to do this, and we have $(1)$.

Adding the second $1$: we can either add it to the last summand in the list, giving us $(2)$, or else append a new $1$ to the summand-list, giving us $(1,1)$.

For each of the remaining four $1$s: similarly, we can add either it to the last summand in the list or else append a new $1$ to the summand-list.

Thus, for each of the last five $1$s there are two choices. Therefore, the number of ways we can proceed is $2^5$.

However, one of these ways produces $(6)$, which we must exclude. Hence, the the number of summand-lists is

$$2^5-1 = 31.$$